# Huge performance decline when accessing object in associative PHP array

Tags: php, oop, command-line

I'm seeing a huge performance decline in a (command line) PHP script, caused by a simple assignment (runtime increase from 0.8 ~ 0.9 seconds to 29.x seconds).

The script first fetches a lot of data from a MySQL database and creates objects of different custom classes. After this fetching (php now uses around 500 MB of RAM) I loop an array of approximately 3'500 `Sample` objects, each of which has an associative array (size around 100 entries) as one of its properties. This array holds `Value` objects, which are small objects with two properties, and the keys are integers smaller than 6'000. This is where I stumbled upon the problem, see this code:

```
foreach ($samples as $id => $s) {    # $s is now a 'Sample' object
    $values = $s->values();          # $values is an array of 'Value' objects

    if (isset($values[$match_id])) {
        $num_tested++;
        # $val = $values[$match_id];     # contains a 'Value' object
        # $val = &$values[...]; -> the loop never ends (!)
    }
}
```

Note that commented line. If I run the code as it appears here, this block runs for about **0.8 to 0.9 seconds**. If I uncomment this single line, the block runs for **almost 30 seconds**. I found that if the array is non-associative (it only contains consecutive keys from 0 to about 100) the runtime only increases to 1.8 ~ 1.9 seconds.
It seems that this happens because of the non-consecutive array keys I use, but then again why does the performance not already decline by calling `isset($values[$match_id])`? Is there a workaround for this or do I have to live with that?

*Running PHP 5.3.0, Zend Engine v2.3.0, Mac OS X Server 10.6.2*

Comment: Can you give us a `print_r($values);die;`?

Comment: I did a `var_dump($values)`, but since one property of a 'Value' object is another object which in turn has an array of other objects, the dump gets much longer than my 10'000 lines of Command Line Buffer.

Comment: In other words, 'Value' objects aren't small objects, but are actually the tops of large object graphs?

Comment: They are small in that they only have one float and one object as properties. But yes, the object graphs grow large, with a lot of cross reference and even circular references further down.

Comment: `$val = &$values[...];` <-- This syntax is wrong, it should be `$val =& $values[...];`

Comment: @R. Bemrose: It can be used either way; the whitespace is ignored.

Comment: @Lucas Oman: I haven't tested it, but I'm fairly sure `=` and `=&` are separate operators.  Just like `= =` and `==` aren't the same.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: `= =` isn't an operator at all. `= &` and `=&` are and are equivalent. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php. Search for '= &'. You'll see that many separate the two characters as a matter of style.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Using it either way results in a non-terminating loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running 5.3, look into the new Spl data structures. They *can* yield a significant performance boost for larger collections, as shown [here](http://blueparabola.com/blog/spl-deserves-some-reiteration) and [here](http://developer.studivz.net/2009/03/18/php-spl-data-structures-benchmark/). Apart from that, it's a bit hard to tell what might be causing the issue. Have you tried to use `xdebug` or `Zend_Debugger` to get more details?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with `xdebug` or the Zend Debugger. Checking out the Spl data structures...

Comment: xdebug and Zend_Debugger allow you to profile your application. They can give you a detailed analysis of what methods are called, how often and how long they take to run. xdebug is free, so why not have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `$val = $values[$match_id]` (assignment by copy) with `$val =& $values[$match_id]` (assignment by reference) and see if it performs better.

Comment: Objects in PHP are always assigned by reference. This would be excellent advice if each $val weren't an object, though.

Comment: I haven't tried that since - as Lucas mentions - objects are always assigned by ref. Interesting thing about this is: **The loop does not come to an end** (at least it did not after 10 minutes, when I killed it)...